# My Broken Calculator

Tags: lateral-thinking

I love my calculator, but something bad happened to it yesterday: It fell from the window.

When I ask some basic questions, my calculator gives me wrong numbers.

Here are the values:

> What's $3\times7$?
>
> = $2$
>
> What's $5\times6$?
>
> = $3$
>
> What's $11\times5$?
>
> = $5$
>
> What's $4\times4$?
>
> = $1$

What's wrong with my calculator? Why does it give these values?

Hint:

> Its processor is running well

$Note: This\space is\space a \space story.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think:

> the monitor / display is broken which results in the answer only showing the first digit:

so,

> 3 x 7 = 2(1)
>  5 x 6 = 3(0)
>  11 x 5 = 5(5)
>  4 x 4 = 1(6)

As for the story:

> You were piss with your maths test result and you blame your calculator!  So it's not 'fell' from the window but rather 'thrown'

Answer (score -1):

According to, that:

> It fell from your window.

Your calculator:

> Has part of the Display Screen damaged.

Therefore:

> It will only print/output the partial result of what you're inputting.